# Creating an editable form for each instance in a queryset

Tags: django, django-forms

What I would like to do is give the user the option of editing their information. When eidt is clicked, the page should pull up all of the information that is for that session. This is an events sign up so if they signed up for multiple events, I'd like them to be able to edit them all.

This is my query

```
    events = signedup.objects.filter(sessionid = session)
```

from here I was thinking that it might be something like this:

```
 for event in events:
    person = inlineformset_factory(comp_name, signedup, can_delete=True)
    form = person(instance = event)
```

- this didn't work for me, maybe I did it wrong?

I used inlineformset_factory because the tables have foreign key relationships, if i dont need it then let me know. What would be the best way of doing this?, I dont want them to be able to add new records, just delete and edit their current ones. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you aren't creating any new instances , you can use modelformset_factory. This will allow you to edit the results that you want; just exchange instance = event to queryset = event and drop the for loop.

Your code should look something like this:

```
person = modelformset_factory(signedup , form=someform, extra = 0, can_delete=True)
form = person(queryset=signedup.objects.filter(sessionid = session))
```

With that you'll get forms for all of the instances that match the queryset and if you specify  a form, you can specify fields and such.